# JQuery Tampermonkey clicking a button with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm currently trying to make a TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey script to enter some info/click some buttons.

The site doesn't use IDs for pretty much anything, mainly only class names. I managed to figure out how to input info but I can't manage to figure out how to click a button that has multiple classes.

Here's an example of a button that I'm trying to click:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block btn-submit waves-effect waves-light">Save</button>
```

Here's my most recent attempt at clicking it:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".btn.btn-success.btn-lg.btn-block.btn-submit.waves-effect.waves-light")[0].click();
```

I've tried a few different suggestions from here on StackOverflow but they don't seem to be working. Not really sure what else to do. I'd appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName` Notice the "s" before "By" ;)

Comment: Already had that before, I took off the s to just play around with it :/ Still nothing sadly, thanks though

Comment: getElementsByClassName is not jQuery and it expects a plain class string with all classes separated by spaces, not dots.

Comment: Yeah, ended up mixing them up a bit. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... You mix jQuery and JavaScript syntax here.

If if want it in JavaScript, this should work:
*(So you won't have to load jQuery in GreaseMonkey)*

```
document.getElementsByClassName(" btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block btn-submit waves-effect waves-light")[0].click();
```

*«names is a string representing the list of class names to match; class names are separated by whitespace»* [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

If you want it in jQuery:

```
$(".btn.btn-success.btn-lg.btn-block.btn-submit.waves-effect.waves-light").first().click();
```

Comment: Oops...Thanks a lot :) Sorry about that, was searching through quite a few different answers and ended up mixing up some stuff at the end. edit: Appreciated :)

Comment: Syntax is the biggest source of issues in coding. ;) Always check the documentation! ;)